# how do carriers actually stabilize nitroglycerine i.e. Dynamite? Do they disrupt the shockwave or free radical chain?

Tags: organic-chemistry

To reiterate-does it prevent a shockwave from propagating, or does it disrupt the light, heat or free radical chain necessary for Detonation?? On a related side-question, does the Blasting Cap then work by breaking up the individual "cells" or by providing free radicals to initiate the explosion?

Comment: I believe the answer is that by binding the explosive chemicals they are as not free to interact with each other.

Comment: It might, of course, be that the key thing that is altered is the activation energy of the initiation step. This is pretty low for liquid nitroglycerine but much higher for dynamite.

Comment: Nitroglycerine is the only chemical involved (actually, with Dynamite, they add sodium nitrate and other additives.) The nitrogens combine and the oxygen burns up the carbon.